# Why can't I compile a .NET MAUI app on Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio-2022, .net-maui

I wanted to start coding something using .NET MAUI, so I updated my VS2022 to *"Version 17.1.0 Preview 6.0"*.
Then I installed these features using *"Visual Studio Installer"* as suggested in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/installation

[image]

Unfortunately when I create a basic MAUI app, I get several errors like this:

> Error NU1012  Platform version is not present for one or more target
> frameworks, even though they have specified a platform: net6.0-android

On developer command line I tried running `dotnet workload list` and got
android
ios
maui-android
maui-maccatalyst

If I try to install some other workload (eg maui or maui-windows) I get an error stating

> Unable to download manifest microsoft.net.workload.emscripten:
> microsoft.net.workload.emscripten.manifest-6.0.200 has not been found
> on NuGet feeds https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json, C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages"

I've also tried to completely remove and reinstall VS2022, without any luck.
I've then tried to run `maui-check` but when it tries to download *Recommendation: Download .NET SDK (6.0.200)* the exe is not valid and the task fails.

Worst part: I tried to install a fresh VS2022 preview on a different pc and everything works flawlessly... but I need it to work on my developmente pc!

.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes cleaning Visual Studio cache helps to solve such issues.

Follow these steps:

---

**Step 1: Clearing component cache and temp files**

1.1 Close Visual Studio and make sure `devenv` process is not present in Task Manager (`Details` tab)

1.2 Delete folder `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0\ComponentModelCache`

Note, that instead of `17.0` in the path it can be another version number, relevant to the installed Visual Studio.

1.3 Delete contents of the folder `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp`

1.4 Launch Visual Studio and check.

If it did not help. Going to step 2.

---

**Step 2: Deleting Visual Studio cache folders**

2.1 Close Visual Studio and make sure `devenv` process is not present in Task Manager (`Details` tab)

2.2 Delete these folders:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon
```

2.3 Launch Visual Studio and check